# Internal Server Error when deleting a Matching Rule

Tags: managed-package, gack, duplicate-matching-rule

We have a production org with an old expired managed package, which we want to uninstall. In order to do so we want to delete an inactive Matching Rule, which we created a long time ago for one of the fields of the package. The Matching Rule is not used by a Duplicate Rule. When we try to delete the Matching Rule, we get an "internal server error" and it is not deleted. (We can edit the Rule though.)

According to my experience, many of Salesforce's "internal server errors" can be circumvented by paying attention to the context. Is there anything we can do to make it possible to delete the Matching Rule?

Error ID: 1641154272-416317 (-1078573919)

Comment: Can you include the GACK ID that is shown along with Internal server error?

Comment: @Swetha Done - and thanks for asking!

Comment: Basically, the GACK is pointing to `java.lang.NullPointerException`,  `SourceMethodName:deleteHook_PostExecute` from backend logs.

Comment: Sounds like we really should create a Salesforce support request, thank you!